# AND and OR operator in same if condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to check the `loginType` is `myAccount` and also to check if `cookie` is defined or not.

Below is my code:

```
if (
    logintype === 'myAccount' && 
    (encodeURIComponent(request.cookies['MY.COOKIE']) === undefined || 
    encodeURIComponent(request.cookies['MY.COOKIE']) === 'undefined')
) {}
```

But the above conditions is not working as expected.

How can I refactor my logic?

Comment: Your sentence is a bit broken. If you check if something "is defined or not", then the answer is always true. Do you want it to be defined, or do you want it to be _not_ defined?

Comment: unsure how encodeURIComponent returns undefined

Comment: I think it should be `cookie !== undefined && cookie !== "undefined` (cookie means the whole part of getting the cookie value) **if you are trying to make sure that cookie is defined**

Comment: yes, I want to make sure that the cookie is der

Comment: what you have written seems fine to me. not sure you want to change anything.